# device to make a power supply sparks safe

Tags: power-supply, inductive, plug

I have an original HP 19V power supply for my laptop. From The first time I bought it I always saw a spark on plug in the wall plug. I notice the same in many ATX power supply.

The problem is that sometimes this sparkles are so huge that switch off the general ower switch of my apartment. Worst problem is the plug damaging. they burn and become black.

I know that this is caused due to the great inductive load of the power supplies.

I always wonder if exist a device or a way to stop this. I thought the easiest way should be install a plug with a switch like this.

[image]

but I'm thinking that this only change the victim of the lightening and do not solve the problem.

Maybe using some "step-resistors" that slow down the electric rush by charging the capacitors of the power supply and then disengage from the power line?

I don't even know if what I'm saying has a meaning, sorry but I'm not a pro with power electronics.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Does the harmful sparks exist when you push the plug into the wall socket or when you pull it out or both? The inductive spark exists at pulling out, the capacitive current inrush exists at pushing in.

Comment: *I know that this is caused due to the great inductive load of the power supplies.* When you see a spark when **unplugging** this is true. However, if you see the spark when **pluggin in** then it is actually the large **capacitive** load of the supply. The caps are empty so a large **inrush current** flows which causes the spark. A proper supply should limit this current using a PTC or resistor. But even many good quality supplies do not have this. A switch can still be a solution as the contact making is more abrupt which is better.

Comment: Normally a NTC thermistor is used to soft start these switcher power supplies. They take a few seconds to cool down to a higher resistance. But it the plug extraction is slow and contact bounces, the surge is great and may trip a breaker near full load from other accessories, not just this unit. The power switch is  better to switch fast than a slow plug extraction. So use the switch and not the plug and wait for a couple seconds before turning back on.

Comment: Sounds like a defective (shorted) NTC to me. Replace the power supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electrical plugs and sockets make poor switches, as you have observed. The problem is that they make and break contact very slowly.

A proper switch, such as built into the device you pictured, uses a toggle-action so that at a certain point the switch snaps and quickly closes or opens the contacts. There may still be some arcing but the contacts should be rated for the load being switched.

In Europe switched sockets are common. The socket can be switched off before plug insertion or removal. This will eliminate the arcing you observed.